# PHP Code working on windows but got stuck on linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache

I'm working on php web application with mysql database.

I used Windows as a development environment, and now while I'm trying to move the application to the production level (CentOS 7) I'm getting some problems.

The problem in short is as follows:

my main page is login page, the action of the form is in some page called `login-action.php`:

**login-action.php**

```
[Some Code]
echo 'before user model';
include_once 'user.class.php'
echo 'after user model';
header ('Location: index.php');
[Some Code]
```

**user.class.php**

```
[Some includes]
echo '  before User Class';
class AppUserModel {
...
...
}
echo 'after User Class';
```

Every thing was working fine in my development environment but on CentOS I'm trying to login but I get stuck in `login-action.php` with the response:

```
before user model  before User Class
```

What Could be the problem.

The things I tried so far:

- set max execution time to unlimited value. (The request is getting so long to respond).
- I don't think the problem is related to mysql because the application is getting stuck before executing any mysql query or even connection to the database.
- I enabled all the errors (E_ALL) but I don't get any error.
- I can't write any thing in the class (as echo) because it's not syntactically correct.
- I don't think `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` could be the problem because it's loading `login-action.php` and `user.class.php` correctly.

What could be the problem or how can I figure it out?

Comment: You also need to [display](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) the generated errors. Whatever, it's normally faster to have a look first at Apache logs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your error log on centOS server.
2. If you don't have access to error log, try using these 3 lines to display error

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   ini_set('scream.enabled', TRUE);
   ```

Remember Linux is case sensitive as opposed to windows, in 90% cases, that is the main issue. Checking proper errors will help you identify the issue